# Difference between SDK, Toolkit and runtime?

Tags: silverlight, sdk, runtime, toolkit

What is difference between a SDK, Toolkit and Runtime patch of any kind of software like Silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Programmers:**

- SDK: Software Developer Kit - only interesting for programmers
- Toolkit: extra tools for the SDK, to help developing

**Enduser:**

- Runtime: minimum enduser plattform files, to get the software running - not the endsoftware itself!

Comment: What makes SDK only interesting to programmers and why runtime lib cannot be used for development? Why SDK cannot be used as runtime?

Comment: Runtime includes everything to get code running but does not compile code. JVM, CLR are runtimes. Without that your code cannot run. SDK are simply lib files and compilation tools that get your programs to compile. In most or all cases sdk installation also  installs runtime because developer would obviously run code after compiling. But in production servers running code there is no need to install SDK (exceptions are there).